Unable to keep date in timezone aware state in flask
Have tried many solutions available on stackoverflow, but none of them solves the issue.
My issue is in my mongodb,  createdAt is stored as Date.

for e.g:  2024-04-13T11:47:19.642Z which is equivalent to Sat Apr 13 2024 17:17:19 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), but when I am retrieveng the data from db it is coming as datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 13, 11, 47, 19, 642000) which is equivalent to Sat Apr 13 2024 11:47:19 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) it is losing its awareness of timezone.
Please note the issue is not with the flask encoder that is correctly converting the date to string using :
class MongoJsonEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj): // line - 2
        if isinstance(obj, datetime):
            return obj.astimezone().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")
        if isinstance(obj, ObjectId):
            return str(obj)
        return json_util.default(obj, json_util.CANONICAL_JSON_OPTIONS)

The problem as per my understanding is the obj in line-2 has already lost its timezone because printing the obj value haere gives 2024-04-13 11:47:19.642000.
Can someone please suggest what I am doing wrong here ?
P.S: Already tried solutions:
Link 1
Link 2
Link 3
